# OS X 10.9.1, Mail 7.1; Mail: Mail rules reset with restart

Tags: mail.app

I am trying to use junk mail custom actions to add additional tags to mail identified as junk. I also unset the "Sender of message is in my Previous Recipients" option. I am finding that each time I close and then restart Mail my custom actions are reset and, also, the "Sender of message is in my Previous Recipients" option is set back to on. This happens reliably.
* How can I reliably diagnose and/or fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the box marked **Documents & Data** in the iCloud preference pane. 
Then try to set up the rules and test it again.